# Passing a not-supervised learning model to cross_val_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What exactly is calculated when we pass something with no `predict` method to `cross_val_score`, like here

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# X is some data, say two dimensional numpy array of reals
cross_val_score(PCA(n_components=10), X)
```

That is, using `cross_val_score` without `y`, and without `predict`.

I asked it previously [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419723/cross-validation-score-for-pca), but there was no reply.

Thanks!

Comment: So, did you actually try it? If not, why? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: Maybe, it's a bit unclear from the statement, but of course, I tried, the result was the standard output of `cross_val_score`, i.e. array of numbers.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, it seems that the answer is simple, though I think I'm asking in a wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, `PCA` has a score method (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.score)): it return "the average log-likelihood of all samples". So your `cross_val_score` returns this score calculated on each cross validation step.